# Change background image php loop

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, onclick

I have a folder of images; I would like to create a page that lists each of them, and clicking them displays that image as the background.
I have got it working using

```
<img .... onclick='document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('img/1.jpg')' >
```

But when I put that into a FOREACH loop it doesn't work.

```
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
    echo "<img .... onclick='document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(".$phpfile.")' />";
}
```

Hope someone can help. Only thing I've found mentioned something about Javascript closures, but I couldn't follow the example it had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotes mismatch. You are prematurely closing your `'` single quotes.

Use a proper IDE to code.

Comment: foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
echo "<img .... onclick=document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(".$phpfile.")' />";
}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to include the path of each image file inside the loop.

```
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
    echo "<img .... onclick='document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('img/".$phpfile."')' />";
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem.

Comment: Try inspecting the element.